# Using structure I need to store 2student information and display their result

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student{
char name[80];
char subject
char country;

};

int main(){
struct student s[10];
int i;
printf("Enter the information of the students:\n");
for(i=0;i<4;++i)
{
printf("\nEnter name of the student: ");
scanf("%s",&s[i].name);
printf("\nEnter the subject of the student: ");
scanf("%s",&s[i].subject);
printf("\nEnter name of the student country: ");
scanf("%s",&s[i].country);
}
printf("\n showing the input of student information: \n");
for(i=0;i<10;++i)
{
printf("\nName: \n");
puts(s[i].name);
printf("\nMajor: \n",s[i].subject);
printf("\nCountry: \n",s[i].country);
}
return 0;
}
```

***while I tried to display the result it is not showing the subject and country.Can u tell me what problem is in my coding?

Answer (score 1):

Is it not showing the subject and the country or is it displaying the first letter only?

I'm not familiar with C but i would suggest you to change

```
char variableName
```

to

```
char variableName[size]
```

As you have in name but you do not have in country and subject. I'm not sure if it is your problem but it might be, I believe just char variableName would store only one character of the users input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a conversion pattern, for `char` it is `%c`

```
printf("\nMajor: %c\n",s[i].subject);
printf("\nCountry: %c\n",s[i].country);
```

Also

```
scanf("%s",&s[i].name);
```

is not correct, it should be

```
scanf("%s", s[i].name); // s[i].name is already an array
```

for reading a char you need to pass the correct conversion pattern too

```
scanf("%c", &s[i].subject);
scanf("%c", &s[i].country);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `struct` should be something like:

```
struct student{
char name[80];
char subject[80];
char country[80];
};
```